# Snakemake on cluster, avoid submitting one rule as a job

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm, snakemake

I'm executing a snakemake pipeline using

```
snakemake --cluster ...
```

It's working nicely right now. However for reasons I won't describe here I want one of my rules not to be submitted as a job, but to be executed in the machine/node where snakemake is running. Is it possible to make such an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can mark rules as local, see the docs: http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html?highlight=Localrules#local-rules